# How to put resources into ready .apk?

Tags: apk

How to put resources into ready .apk ?
I created an apk program that read text from .txt file in res/raw.
And load image from assets.
When i open apk with winrar and replace images or .txt
, apk file not install.
Eclipse error : the file *.txt have not certificate.
I have the project of apk and cert key.

Now the question is :

What can i do that apk file install after change resources?

Comment: Not any one answer me?
I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Just build apk again with resource included.

BTW, you file should be in `assets` folder.